# How to get all academic degrees from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get all [academic degrees](http://dbpedia.org/page/Academic_degree) from dbpedia. 
I'm completely new to SPARQL. The following returns no results

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
?e rdfs:label "Academic degree" .
}
```

Comment: Your query is looking for all resources whose label is "Academic degree", so does not work, You could look for all resources that have as http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject the category http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Academic_degrees.

Comment: @AKSW thanks for pointing in the right direction. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to take care of it, although I believe it's limited

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>

SELECT ?degree, ?name
WHERE
{
   { ?degree rdf:type yago:AcademicDegree106697331 . }
   ?degree rdfs:label ?name
}
```